# Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException: There is no column with name 'deleted_at' on table 'users'

Tags: php, laravel, api, testing, integration-testing

I built an API (back: Laravel & front: angular) and I would like to test my API.
I'm a beginner on Laravel and i've got problems when I want to do some integration test. Indeed, I tried this little test:

```
class userTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testExample()
    {
        $response = $this->getJson('/api/listUsers');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

}
```

and I always have this error:

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException: There is no column with name 'deleted_at' on table 'users'.
```

While yet 'deleted_at' exist in my table 'users, so I don't understand, I searched on internet but no one got this error when running the phpunit command.

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->date('date_of_birth');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');

        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropSoftDeletes();
        });
    }
}
```

And my User class:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    // 1. Dépendances
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Notifiable;


    // 2. properties

    protected $appends = ['fullname', 'age'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password','date_of_birth'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at', 'pivot',
    ];
    protected $table = 'users';




    // 3. getters & setters
    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }

    public function getFullNameAttribute() {
        return ucfirst($this->firstname) . ' ' . ucfirst($this->lastname);
    }

    public function getAgeAttribute()
    {
        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['date_of_birth'])->age;
    }

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }


    // 4. other methods
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class);
    }

}
```

Can I have some help pls ??

Comment: Please share your User class.

Comment: did you use soft delete ?

Comment: Yes i'm using soft delete

Comment: did you get this error while migrating the files ?

Comment: I shared my User class @El_Vanja

Comment: No I can run "php artisan migrate" without error but when I'm running "vendor\bin\phpunit" I get this error @AzaharAlam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running below commands.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Also, Try to remove the deleted_at column from $hidden attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the soft-delete and it works now